# Weird use case for `AutoFilter` operator `xlAnd`

Tags: excel, vba

I found this line of code which uses column 1 of the table `tbl` to filter the table `tbl`:

```
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>#*", Operator:=xlAnd
```

I don't understand what this does, because it does not match with, how `Operator:=xlAnd` should normally be used ([link](https://software-solutions-online.com/range-autofilter/)). Usually if when using `Operator:xlAnd` we need also the `Criteria2`, e.g.:

```
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="January", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="February"
```

So why tehre is no `Criteria2` in the code and what does it actually do?

Comment: `Operator` is an `Optional` parameter, its default value being `xlAnd`. So, with it there or without, nothing is changed in the `AutoFilter` behavior. It can be omitted also in the second example. I mean, `tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="January",  Criteria2:="February"` will work the same, even not giving a value to `Operator`. It works the same, due to the fact that its default value is 'xlAnd`, anyhow...

Comment: I haven't found an official documentation for the `xlAnd`. Do you maybe have any reference? Explanation is really not sufficient [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlautofilteroperator)...

Comment: @FaneDuru Could you also elaborate a bit on `"<>#*"` criteria. I know that `<>` targets the *"non-blank fields"*, `#` is a *"digit"* and `*` is a *"wildcard"* targetting any kind of character or a digit. What kind of cells would this match?

Comment: The operation itself description does not matter too much. Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter), please and see what I told you above. Then, the `wildcard` operator replaces anything. In other words, it can be interpreted as **return any cases of strings which do not start with "#"**.

Comment: If you use it as `tbl.Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>#*", Criteria2:="<>$*"`, the return will select only strings **not starting with "#" AND not starting with "$"**...

Comment: Aha! So we specify `<>`, `><` or `=` at the beginning of the `Criteria1` to tell what kind of cell we are filtering and then this is followed by any kind of characters (including the wildcards). I hope I now understand!

Comment: Yup... this is the meaning of shown filter criteria...

Comment: Thank you. Now all is clear. If you post an answer I will make sure to accept it.

Comment: Not necessarily, I think... I just tried explaining the function normal behavior. Our main goal here is to make as many people as possible learning. If they will read the above comments, they will learn... :) Then, I do not care too much about notoriety points. I had a personal target of 20000 and it has been accomplished some times before. I place answers only  for things not being able to be answered in a comment, of for something complex, which looks like a challenge. Usually, involving arrays solutions, even not only....